# why the odd results adding floats in javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I have javascript code like this:

```
var strikePrice = parseFloat(this.props.data.strike).toFixed(1);
var commission = parseFloat(this.props.commission / 100).toFixed(2);
var callInMoney = parseFloat(strikePrice + this.state.callPrice + commission).toFixed(2);
var putInMoney = parseFloat(strikePrice - this.state.putPrice - commission).toFixed(2);

console.log("strikePrice: " + strikePrice + " commission: " + commission);
console.log("callprice: " + this.state.callPrice + " putprice: " + this.state.putPrice);
console.log("call: " + callInMoney + " put: " + putInMoney);
```

and the output is this:

```
strikePrice: 34.0 commission: 0.08
callprice: 0 putprice: 0
call: 34.00 put: 33.92
```

That is wrong.   The call should be 34.08 (8 cents higher) just like the put is 8 cents lower.

Why is the results not correct?

Thank you
Matt

Comment: toFixed turns them into string, if you want to keep treating them as numbers use parseFloat or Number method

Comment: You'll generally want to use `parseFloat()` on individual values rather than the result of a calculation. In this order, the `+` can concatenate rather than add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string so you're actually doing some string concatenation rather than the arithmetic you expect.

Check out what happens when you just print out your initial addition.

```js
var strikePrice = parseFloat('34').toFixed(1);
var commission = parseFloat('0.08').toFixed(2);
console.log(strikePrice + 0 + commission);
```

Instead, you'll need to convert those strings to numbers first.

```js
var strikePrice = parseFloat('34').toFixed(1);
var commission = parseFloat('0.08').toFixed(2);

strikePrice = parseFloat(strikePrice);
commission = parseFloat(commission);

console.log(strikePrice + 0 + commission);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now that you point it out, it should have been obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

`strikePrice + this.state.callPrice + commission`

Evaluates to this value:

`"34.000.08"`

Because `commission` is a string value, which is because `[toFixed()][1]` takes an integer and returns a string.

You need to refactor your code so that `commission` is a float value, or so that you call `parseFloat()` again on the parameters of line 3.

I can't comment on why `putInMoney` works for you. For me it gave `"NaN"`.

Comment: Thanks.  It makes sense now.  When I was looking at it, I didn't realize toFixed returns a string.